# Listen to Observable.timer and emit to parent component

Tags: angular, timer, observable, countdown, eventemitter

I have a countdown component using `Observable.timer` which is used in a parent component. When it's used, it takes `@Input() seconds: string` from the parent component that is used as which number to begin for countdown `ex: 60`. Now, I want to emit the countdown number `@Output() checkTime` to the parent component to disable a button once it reaches `0`.

So I subscribed the countdown number to `checkTime` event emitter. But as a result, countdown doesn't stop it at 0 and it keeps decrementing. Can anyone see the problem below?

register.component.html

```
<tr *ngFor="let course of courses">            
    <td>
        <button class="btn btn-info" [disabled]="counter === 0"> Register</button>              
    </td>  
    <td>
        <countdown [seconds]="60" (checkTime)="checkTimeExpired($event);"></countdown>
    </td>         
</tr>
```

countdown.component.ts

```
import { Component, Input, Output, OnInit, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core'
import { Observable, Subscription } from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Component({
  selector: 'countdown',
  template: '{{ countDown | async | formatTime }}'
})
export class CountdownComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() seconds: string;
  @Output() checkTime: EventEmitter<number> = new EventEmitter();
  countDown: any;
  counter: number;
  private subscription: Subscription;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.counter = parseInt(this.seconds, 10);
    this.countDown = Observable.timer(0, 1000)
                    .take(this.counter)
                    .map(() => --this.counter)

    this.subscription = this.countDown.subscribe(t => {
        this.checkTime.emit(this.counter)
    });                   
  }
}
```

register.component.ts

```
counter: number;

checkTimeExpired(evt) {
   this.counter = evt;   
}
```

Countdown stops at 0 if I don't use subscription.

```
this.subscription = this.countDown.subscribe(t => {
    this.checkTime.emit(this.counter)
});
```

Sorry if there is already a relevant question, but help this newly entered angular user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue is that you're decoupling the Observable's value with an arbitrary variable. Usually you want an Observable stream to transform a value for you -- that's half of what RxJS is about.

Problem is with `.map(() => --this.counter)`. The `map` operator transforms the stream of values and returns the new value. Here, you're transforming the Observable value into `--counter`; there's the problem. The `--counter` will return `counter - 1` and decrement `counter`, but the value is completely **decoupled** from the Observable stream. What does that mean?

Controlling that value from outside of that Observable makes that Observable **hot**. It's values can stream to different subscribers, but the values can change due to outside factors. (Remember that an Observable doesn't execute until it's subscribed to)

But...you have only one subscriber, so that's not a problem, right? Actually, the Angular `async` pipe *also* subscribes to Observables under the hood. That means your Observable has been subscribed to **twice**, which means there's two timers counting down, which means there are two streams executing that `map` function -- which means every second, `this.counter` is being decremented **twice**.

I'd recommend combining the Observable's **timer** value and the *actual* time value, and then emit your event only as a side effect:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    const start = parseInt(this.seconds, 10);
    this.countDown = Observable.timer(0, 1000)
                    .take(start + 1) // add one, so zero is included in emissions.
                    .map(i => start - i) // decrement the stream's value and return
                    .do(s => this.checkTime.emit(s)) // do a side effect without affecting value

  }
```

The `async` pipe will subscribe to it and start the emissions. Best part is, the `async` pipe automatically cleans up the subscription when it's destroyed.

Another idea is using `takeWhile`, which is a more declarative way to say how many emissions should be taken, and completes when the provided expression is false:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    const start = parseInt(this.seconds, 10);
    this.countdown = Observable.timer(0, 1000)
                .map(i => start - i) // decrement the stream's value and return
                .takeWhile(i => i >= 0)
                .do(s => this.checkTime.emit(s)) // do a side effect without affecting value

  }
```

Hope that helps clear up some confusion!

Comment: This is certainly one of the best answers I got. Nice explanations and works like a charm.

Comment: Small question, I find that if I pass 60 seconds to this `Observable.timer(0, 1000)`, it runs slower than the real clock, maybe about 20 seconds behind. Would it be related to emission?

Comment: hmm...by 'real clock' do you mean a start point kicked off somewhere else in the app, or does the timer just start 20 seconds late? Or are the emissions longer than one second?

Comment: If you have an example on github or can put one on a fiddle, I'd be happy to look as well

Comment: Hi joh04667, this is very interesting. I figured out when I switch between tabs on chrome and come back to the original tab with timer started after some time, I see that it's not working as intended - slower. You can check related info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45351279/angular-rxjs-observable-interval-not-triggering-properly-on-background-tabs-in). Works well if I don't switch tab. `setInterval()` seems to be the solution, but not sure how to apply in my logic when there is `.map`, `.do`, etc is already in use.

Answer (score -1):

You can try to stop the countdown on the subscription, the timer will run on the background.

[Stackblitz Rebuild](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ddy8oe)